# Rails get only records with calculated attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to only choose records with a calculated attribute that meets a certain criteria.

Customer model has a `lateness` method that calculates the difference between a value and the current time. This part is not the issue.

This, from the Customer controller, works, but is really gross:

```
def index
  customers = Customer.all
  @customers = []

  customers.each do |customer|
    if customer.lateness > 5
      @customers.push(customer)
    end
  end
end
```

There has to be a more elegant way, I read the whole docs on ActiveRecord Query Interface and couldn't find anything.

Comment: have you thought about scope?

Comment: That might work. Side note: can you pass parameters with scope?

Comment: Yes, you can. check this out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments

Answer (score 1):

the calculation is in the model?

then

```
@customers = Customer.all.select{|c| c.lateness > 5}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a dynamic attribute written in Ruby as part of your Active Record filtering criteria.

However, in your particular case, unless there is a lot more happening in the method than you describe, you could just have the database do the calculation.

If for example your `lateness` method looked like:

```
def lateness
  due_date - Time.now
end
```

You could make a where clause (database specific, so be careful) that looked like the following if you were using Postgres:

`where('due_date::date - current_date() > ?', 5)`

The 5 doesn't have to be injected like that but in case you want to make that variable, that's how you would do that.

Comment: It's a little bit more involved than I described. It's not a value of the Customer, but rather a value of a nested resource that belongs to the Customer. So I don't think I can do it directly with the database. Thank you, though!